# Security of RSA

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cryptography

The proof of security of RSA I'm familiar with is if you could compute  $$(p-1)(q-1),$$ then you could compute $p$ and $q$ from $$p+q=pq-(p-1)(q-1)-1$$  and $pq=n$.

A question I have is: is it clear under reasonable assumptions on $p,q$ that being able to decrypt $M^e$  implies you can calculate $(p-1)(q-1)$?

Comment: No, it is not at all clear; in fact it is still unproven. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_problem) for more information.

Comment: Note that you can produce decryptable messages $M=N^d$ where you know that $M^e=N$

Comment: It has not even be shown that RSA is safe if the enemy is unable to factor the number. Moreover, there are several attacks for unsuitable methods to use the factors for the code , for example too small exponents $e$.